# How much potential volume in a rocket's tank is actually used for fuel?

Tags: rockets, fuel

Of the potential volume of a liquid fueled rocket's propellant tank, how much of that volume is actually dedicated to propellants (since [ullage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ullage) is needed because of pressurization, boiloff, etc.)?

Particularly, I'm looking for this measure with respect to the following fuels

- RP-1,
- LOX, and
- LH2 fuels.

[image: Note the gaseous hydrogen in the Ariane 5 EPC: that's the ullage space I'm asking about.]

Answer (score 3):

[This report](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19990009082.pdf) has the ullage volume of the LOX tank on the X-34 at 6%, and RP-1 at 0.5 to 1.5%.